# Why Goddess Lakshmi abondoned the universe?

Tags: scripture, lakshmi

The Narada Purana mentiones the origin of Pausha Purnima:-

> 68. **Formerly this universe was abondoned by Lakshmi**. So Hari, Indra, Soma, Tisya and Brhaspati these five made the universe still more dignified and decorated by means of the sports of festivities of blessedness on the full moon day coinciding with the Pushya constellation.

The above one mentiones that Lakshmi left the universe. But, Why Goddess Lakshmi abondoned the universe? Does any other scriptures mention the reason?